# Performing multiple API calls before dispatching an Action an NgRx Effect

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-effects, switchmap

I'm using NgRx `@Effect` and for some effect I need to perform 2 API calls: the result of the first one is used in the second one and the I want to dispatch an `Action` with the 2nd API call as `payload` this way :

```
@Effect()
FetchDetails() {
  return this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(actions.SOME_ACTION),
    switchMap((action: SomeAction) => this.myService.getContext()),
    switchMap((ctx: Context) => this.myService.fetchDetails(action.id, ctx.requesterType)
      .pipe(
        map((response: Details) => new SetDetails(response)),
        catchError(err => {return of(new SetFetchDetailsError(err))})
      )
  )
}
```

Using a double `switchMap` like this I can't access `action.id` so I think my operators orchestration is not correct !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this in pipe inside:

```
@Effect()
FetchDetails() {
  return this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(actions.SOME_ACTION),
    switchMap((action: SomeAction) => this.myService.getContext().pipe(
      switchMap((ctx: Context) => this.myService.fetchDetails(action.id, ctx.requesterType)
    ))
      .pipe(
        map((response: Details) => new SetDetails(response)),
        catchError(err => {return of(new SetFetchDetailsError(err))})
      )
  )
}
```

Comment: Yes it working like this ! Thanks !
I found another way to do it using contactMap I'll post it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a new function, which will call `getContext()`, but will return what you need. Something like :

```js
getContextAction(action: SomeAction): Observable<any> {
  return this.getContext().pipe(
    map(ctx => { action, ctx });
}
```

Then

```js
@Effect()
FetchDetails() {
return this.actions.pipe(
  // ...
  switchMap((action: SomeAction) => this.myService.getContextAction(action)),
  switchMap((value) => this.myService.fetchDetails(value.action.id, value.ctx.requesterType)
  // ...
}
```

You can also edit you current function `getContext()` in order to return the given action.

Comment: I'm sorry but both are not accepted syntaxically :(

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: my IDE is not accepting the syntax .. Here is a screenshot : https://ibb.co/cgb5MSd

Comment: Can't see it, if it's because of destructuration, I've updated my post.

Comment: Yes it was because of destructuration. But even the second solution isn't working ... here is a screenshot : https://prnt.sc/20zdqjy

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I found using `concatMap` operator :

```
@Effect()
    FetchApiDetails() {
        return this.actions.pipe(
            ofType(apis.FETCH_SELECTED_API_DETAILS),
            concatMap((action: FetchSelectedApiDetails) =>
                this.contextInit.getContext()
                    .pipe(
                        switchMap((ctx: Context) => this.apisManagementService.fetchApiDetails(action.apiId, ctx.requesterType)
                            .pipe(
                                map((response: ApiDetails) => new SetApiDetails(response)),
                                catchError(err => {
                                    return of(new SetFetchApiDetailsError(err))
                                })
                            )
                        ),
                        catchError(err => {
                            console.log('An error happened when fetching context ' + err);
                            return of(err);
                        })
                    )
            )
        );
    }
```